# Incorrect syntax near ')', possible incorrect use of substring() or charindex()?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, vba

I'm trying to run an ADODB query on a SQL Server database instance of ProjectWise, using the query defined by the following string:

```
select 
dms_audt.o_acttime as actionTime,
dms_stat.o_statename as state,
dms_doc.o_filename as filename,
dms_doc.o_projectno as project 
from dms_audt 
inner join 
dms_stat 
on dms_audt.o_numparam2=dms_stat.o_stateno 
inner join dms_doc on dms_audt.objguid=dms_doc.o_docguid 
where substring(dms_doc.o_filename,1,4)="abcd") 
and charindex(dms_doc.o_filename,"efgh")=0
```

VBA is giving me a runtime error of:

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'
```

which makes me think that I'm either using `substring()` or `charindex()` incorrectly.  I've received this error regardless of whether I wrap the **abcd** and **efgh** strings in single or double quotes.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra bracket.

this > `where substring(dms_doc.o_filename,1,4)="abcd")
        and charindex(dms_doc.o_filename,"efgh")=0`

needs to be:

`where substring(dms_doc.o_filename,1,4)='abcd' and charindex(dms_doc.o_filename,'efgh')=0`

Comment: Should be single quotes. Double quotes will error out expecting a column named `[abcd]`.

Comment: great, thanks!  I don't have SQL Server installed on my workstation; is there a good online debugger I can use to track down this kind of syntax problem?  I tried SQLFiddle and it just gave me the same error.

Comment: @sigil: SQL Fiddle is probably your best bet if you don't have SQL Server installed.